# Unzip with WinRar in Qt(C++) using QProcess - extract directory problem

Tags: c++, qt, zip, extract, qprocess

I have this code bellow to unzip folder. It works but I do not know how to change extraction directory. Everytime, it extracts folder to directory where is my .exe file of my program. I tried some things but every time, it just extracts there. I want to choose directory.

```
QString program = "c:/program files/winRAR/winRAR.exe";

QStringList arguments;
arguments << "x"; // extract files and directories
arguments << "-y"; // suppress questions
arguments << "-o" + QDir::toNativeSeparators(extractDirectory);
arguments << QDir::toNativeSeparators(zipFileDirectory);

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

I would say, there is problem in way of writing extractDirectory behind -o argument but not sure.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try `arguments << "-o" << QDir::toNativeSeparators(extractDirectory)` instead to pass it as a separate argument, maybe winrar's command line parsing does not tolerate sticking arguments to flags?

Comment: Tried but doesnt work. It doesnt even extract that file now.

Comment: [Does WinRar even support `-o`?](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPCommands.htm) Can you run the desired command in cmd?

Comment: Thank you, I totaly forgot it hasnt. Thanks to you, I tried somethnig else. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some comments, I find out that -o argument doesnt exist in WinRAR and this is solution.

```
QString program = "c:/program files/winRAR/winRAR.exe";

QStringList arguments;
arguments << "x"; // extract files and directories
arguments << "-y"; // suppress questions
arguments << QDir::toNativeSeparators(zipFileDirectory);
arguments << QDir::toNativeSeparators(extractDirectory);

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

Thank you everyone.